# Can we show USA location in MKMapView on initial load for user disabled location access?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I need to show default USA location in `MKMapview` if the user disable location access. i have used below code and it works.

`CLLocationCoordinate2D coord =     CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.999733,-98.678503);

MKCoordinateSpan spanOfUS = MKCoordinateSpanMake(13.589921, 14.062500);

MKCoordinateRegion USRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, span); [self.mapView setRegion: USRegion animated: YES];`

My Question is, Can we set map to some other location apart from user current location if user restrict permission access. Is it a correct way, Any restriction from Apple?
I don't know how much its a perfect way to handle location permission access.
Any suggestion. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: apple has approve , we can show the static location in map, is this possible to show

Comment: Thanks. Yes it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions only required when you want to get user's private information. If you not affecting with user's privacy then nothing is restricted.

For example, If you want to know user's current location or location updates of user then it must requires permission.

But If you are showing static location using any lat-long, there no restriction from apple and you not require permission of user. for example, if some one have contact us screen in their app and they are showing their address in text and also on map then it's fine.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome.. :) If you feel it is helful then accept the answer so, other people with similar issue can use it :)

Comment: OK, but I can't vote since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I am saying to accepting answer "as a right tick' beside the answer!!

Comment: Sorry . I did. Thanks/